# How do you get the direction of steepest ascent?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

The directional derivative tells us the rate of change given a direction of a unit vector. But how do you get that unit vector?

I know it says that the gradient points to that direction, but I just can't grasp this.

Looking at gradients of a 3-d function it seems they differ by size and direction. The size is the steepness of slope. That one is derived from the dot product the directional vector and the gradient, I believe?

Anyway can somebody can where and how do you get the direction of the vector. [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/directional-derivative-introduction) the directional vector is suposed to be given.